# Material that can provide soft flexibility, while maintaining conduction "accuracy"

Tags: material-science

I hope material search may be valid here.

Is there a material that can be shaped as a few millimeters thick sheet, that can be placed on top a touch surface (e.g. iOS/Android tablet, Wacom drawing pad, etc..) that would fulfil these properties:

1. The material would be *"responsive"* in the direction perpendicular to its flat dimension - once pressure is exerted by an finger/object in some location on its surface, it squeezes down around the point where the pressure is applied. Once pressure is removed, it resumes its original straight contour around that point.
2. Soft for human touch - the amount of pressure necessary for the former property, is such that a human does not need to make much effort to get the material to flex that way.
3. The material is *conductive* such that touch input seamlessly works
4. Somehow conduction isn't skewed in that form factor, in the sense that the underlying touch surface feels the touch point as close as possible to the coordinate pair where the touch occurs on this material. A different way to put this is that *conduction follows perpendicularly to the point of contact with little or no divergence* sideways (otherwise it would project a weaker electric signal at the point of touch and noise around that point - towards the underlying surface).
5. Trivial and hopefully easy - can be glued on top a touch surface with one type of glue compound or another without impeding any of the properties, preferably 
   remaining removable just like regular touch surface protectors.

Comment: If you are not aware of such a material, it could also be very helpful if posted about the proper names for those properties, or the more correct jargon to use to describe them ..

Comment: This is not a physics question, to begin with, but I think this may be what you are looking for: http://www.fujipoly.com/usa/products/zebra-elastomeric-connectors/ and http://www.zaxisconnector.com/Z-Carbon-LCD-Elastomeric-Connectors.shtml. These are called "elsatomeric connectors" and I have seen them in 1D and 2D configurations, but I don't think they will work the way you imagine, though. Modern capacitive sensors probably won't respond in a useful way to these materials. What, by the way, stops you from using a customized resistive touchpad?